# How to use border image along one side only?

Tags: html, css

I have an image that I'd like to set as the border on an element, but only as the bottom border: [image: the border image] <- It's teeny - but it's right there.

Here is what I've got so far:

```
<style>
body { margin: 0; padding: 10px; }
    h1 {
background-color: red;
    border: solid transparent;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-image: 2 repeat url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAADCAYAAACqPZ51AAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAB9JREFUeNpiZGBgOMOABv7//48uxMDEQCQgWiFAgAEAjqADz4EvP7IAAAAASUVORK5CYII=");
}
</style>
<h1>Bacon</h1>
<p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet tenderloin drumstick ribeye filet mignon t-bone beef ribs. Tri-tip venison turkey salami drumstick chicken pastrami. Frankfurter pork jowl ball tip tail.</p>
```

Or see JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eqpt5/.

As you can see, this puts the border image on both the top and bottom (and the sides - though you can't see it). How can I put a border image on only the bottom using `border-image`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Change `border-width:2px` to `border-width:0 0 2px`

In this way you are actually setting border bottom width 2px and other sides width equal to zero

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/naveenksh/eqpt5/3/

Comment: This is a very nice solution, however it won't work when, for example, I need borders on all the sides, and border image on only one of them. Any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: @ТомицаКораћ any luck achieving that?

Comment: @AryanJ-NYC 'fraid not. Still no clue.

Answer (score 2):

```
border-bottom-width: 1px;
```

Put it after your other border stuff to override a specific border side.

you could use short hand but i think this is easier for readability.

Answer (score 1):

you can give `border-top:none;` its working fine as per your desired results...

**CSS**

```
h1 {
background-color: red;
    border: solid transparent;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-image:url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAADCAYAAACqPZ51AAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAB9JREFUeNpiZGBgOMOABv7//48uxMDEQCQgWiFAgAEAjqADz4EvP7IAAAAASUVORK5CYII=") 2 repeat;
    border-top:none;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eqpt5/6/)**

Comment: you can give border-top:0;border-left:0;border-right:0; as naveen did that.........

Comment: give can give border-width:0 from all three required sides

Answer (score -2):

In addition to the top answer. Since border-image overrides the border-style, to get borders for the other sides just wrap the div with another div then declare the borders.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">             //div with border style
 <div id="content"></div>      //div with border image
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
border-top: 1px solid black;
border-right: 1px solid black;
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
#content {
border-image: url(../images/blue-bg.png) 0 0 0 50;
border-left-width: 10px;
```

}