# How to use repeated image as border with gaps

Tags: html, css

How can i achieve a dashed horizontal line from an image and control the gaps between each in HTML/CSS? I think javascript is to overkill for this.

[image]

Im facing this problem at the yellow marker, so i need it dynamic.

Maybe someone has a good idea.

Comment: What is the "problem at the yellow marker" exactly?

Comment: It is unclear what exactly you're asking or what you're trying to achieve. You should also include the code you have tried to help us help you.

Comment: Exactly described, the last repeated image (where the marker is) should also be a dash. Now its a half dash :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `border-image` property (used it few years ago, worked good but you will need to remember that images scale under different independent-pixels resolutions (short version: different Android devices can render it scaled up/down), but maybe its just case of proper scale unit - I was creating different image sizes for that):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image

Comment: Maybe i can use it with SVG?

Comment: Try and give all of us feedback : )

Comment: Ok, i read about this border-image and slices. My question is, do I need the fully 9-Slice method or can i do only the x-Axis part of 3 slices?

Comment: You can do it only at selected edge as described here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13486187/how-to-use-border-image-along-one-side-only